# ki tisa: menorah versus menorah ha'tehorah

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mishkan-tabernacle, parashat-ki-tisa, menorah--in-temple, written-torah

In parashat Ki Tisa two similar passages are written regarding the Ohel Mo'ed (Tent of Meeting). In the first ([Shemot 30:27](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9891/jewish/Chapter-30.htm#v27)) Moshe Rabbenu is ordered to anoint the kelim with the shemen mischat-kodesh, in the second ([Shemot 31:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9892/jewish/Chapter-31.htm#v8)) the construction of the Ohel Mo'ed is ordered. I'm in confusion about (a) do these passages describe the same ohel mo'ed? And if so (or even if not so) why is the menorah described differently:

Shemot 30:27

> אֶת־הַשֻּׁלְחָן֙ וְאֶת־כָּל־כֵּלָ֔יו **וְאֶת־הַמְּנֹרָ֖ה** וְאֶת־כֵּלֶ֑יהָ
>   וְאֵ֖ת מִזְבַּ֥ח הַקְּטֹֽרֶת

Shemot 31:8

> וְאֶת־הַשֻּׁלְחָן֙ וְאֶת־כֵּלָ֔יו **וְאֶת־הַמְּנֹרָ֥ה הַטְּהֹרָ֖ה**
>   וְאֶת־כָּל־כֵּלֶ֑יהָ וְאֵ֖ת מִזְבַּ֥ח הַקְּטֹֽרֶת

In Shemot 30:27 the menorah is simply referred to as '*menorah*', whereas in Shemot 31:8 it is referred to as the '*menorah-ha'tehorah*'.

If the annointing had made it tehorah, why not all the other annointed kelim? If it is a new ohel, what is different about the 'new' menorah? I can't seem to find commentary that discusses why only the menorah has the 'tehorah' added as a suffix.  It probably means I'm missing something extremely obvious, but I haven't figured it out yet.  Rashi explains that 'ha'tehorah' refers to 'pure', to say, it was made of pure gold. Wasn't the first menorah of pure gold?